# Overriding CSS files using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I want to dynamically choose between a CSS file for my website.

i have 4 different Css files overriding each other but how can i choose between them to be used in my website using JavaScript?

Comment: Look at [Less](http://lesscss.org/). Or, you can simply append your link elements to your head section dynamically using vanilla JS or jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple DOM based solution would be:

```
function loadCssFile(filename) {
    var fileref = document.createElement("link")
    fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
    fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
    fileref.setAttribute("href", filename);
    if (typeof fileref != "undefined") {
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
    }
}
if (somecondition) {
    loadCssFile("mystyle.css");
} else {
    loadCssFile("default.css");
}
```

OR using document.write,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (somecondition) {
        document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />');
    }
</script>
```

And if you are using jQuery,

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />');
```

Answer (score 1):

This function create a link tag with the url you give, and then put it at the end of your head tag.

```
function loadCss(url) {
  var l = document.createElement('link');
  l.rel='stylesheet';
  l.href= url;
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(l);
}
```

and then :

```
loadCss('css/myCss');
```

with if else condition or a switch you can now choose which css you want to load.

Answer (score 1):

You can just put some condition in javascpt and put you html in a string:

```
  <script>
    function change_css()
    {
      var name;
      if(condition1)
      {
         name=//css filename here;
         htmlstring="<link rel='stylesheet' href='CSS/"+name".css' type='text/css'>";
       }
       else if(condition2)
       {
         name=//css filename here;
         htmlstring="<link rel='stylesheet' href='CSS/"+name".css' type='text/css'>";
        }
        $("#divname").html(htmlstring);

    }

    <script>
```